# My only son is the heir to a city, so my titles will be inherited by my daughter. How to fix this?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

Title kinda says it all - i have a son and a daughter, and he is the heir to some city i can't even find(it says city of York, and i have created a Republic from the Duchy of York, so there is Republic of York, Grand City of York and that's it - the city in the County of York is called something else - the title search finds it and sends me to the county, but there's nothing named City of York there).

What can i do to change this? I don't want my vassals to have the -10 modifier for having a female heir, and i don't want the little girl inheriting(i am ~40 years old, i might die soon, and she's 2), my rule isn't all that stable(I am Richard de Normandie, second son of William the Bastard, and the first to rule after William's death, and altough i managed to replace most of the Anglo-Saxon vassals with Normans, as well as remove most threats - all of the Godwins i could get my hands to are bishops or dead, save Harold, who is a castrated count under a powerful Norman Duke, and his biggest son, also a count under a powerful Norman Duke, same goes for all of the Hwicces, i don't want to risk it, especially with a strong French King with de jure claim on Normandy, ambitious Breton Petty Queen, whose husband and sister i have killed, and a Scottish King who hates me for taking one of his counties and executing some of his family).

So yes, how can i remove my son from the order of succession of a city? He's in my court, so i can send him to be tutored somewhere(in a few years, he's 4-5), or give him titles(altough i prefer not to, i like to have my family near me, so that i can control their actions[apart from when i send 3rd or 4th brothers to start a branch in some foreign County/Duchy/Kingdom]).

Comment: Unless you have some serious health issues or spend too much time leading troops, you should still expect to live for at least 20 years. You might even be able to father more children when you get a young wife.

Comment: True, but i want to be prepared for worst case scenario. My wife is 38, and i can't divorce her(the bloody Pope doesn't like me), and a plot won't succed, she's liked by everyone.

Comment: When you want to get a divorce but the pope won't let you, there are options. You could either set up an anti-pope or pull off a Henry VIII and convert to a heresy without a pope... but then you might have yet another problem on your hands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally I would strongly advise against what I am about to suggest, but desperate times etc.

Grant your son a title. The only reason I can figure that he would be heir to a City is if he is set to inherit a position in the Republic. The game will not allow a landed Feudal character to inherit a Republican title. So, if your son has a title, even a single Feudal Barony, he will be a landed Feudal character, ineligible for the Republican succession.

Of course, this will mean you no longer have the full measure of control over your son that you usually would. I suggest setting him up a betrothal before granting him a title. At this early age you have little idea how his future bride will turn out so aim for good genetics, or possibly for someone that is within your realm so that you can educate the daughter as well. Once the betrothal is set your son will almost certainly honor it when he comes of age.

As for education, he will pick his own guardian when he turns 6, but if you offer to educate him as you usually would you can replace that guardian. Your son will accept the change as you are his father.

Comment: Actually, a weird thing happened, out of nowhere he suddenly wan't that City's heir anymore. I did end up giving him a county title(just before his marriage to a Duchess, so that their children end up in his court and don't get some different culture[she was Dutch, i am Norman]).